# Using different certificate for both transport and message when creating client for Axis2 web service

Tags: c#, ssl, soap-client, ws-security

I'm trying to write a client for an axis2 web service that requires signing the message with one certificate and using different certificate for transport.

I have the WSDL but after importing the service using SvcUtil I have a problem what binding to use for that and ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate seems to allow only one certificate and if i set in binding Security.Mode.TransportWithMessageCredential and set both credential types to to both transport and message i get no certs for TLS in tracing.

Link to WSDL with all the XSDs including oasis-200401-wss-security-utility-1.0.xsd

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lIiTyw4jWdiraR0JnZ3MM1doYDq9Bq1S/view?usp=sharing

If i only do transport then tls works but i get wsse:security header missing from the server.

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        
        System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding bindingws=new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
        bindingws.Security=new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity();
        bindingws.Security.Mode=System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport;
        //bindingws.Security.Mode=System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        bindingws.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType=System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        //bindingws.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType=System.ServiceModel.MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
        
        eskierowanie.ObslugaSkierowaniaWSClient os=new XRis.eskierowanie.ObslugaSkierowaniaWSClient(bindingws,new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/services/ObslugaSkierowaniaWS"));
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 tls_cert=new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"certificate-tls.p12","Password", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 wss_cert=new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"certificate-wss.p12","Password", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
        os.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate=tls_cert;
        
        //filling the request
        eskierowanie.KontekstMT kontekst=new XRis.eskierowanie.KontekstMT();
        eskierowanie.WyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcyRequest wsur=new XRis.eskierowanie.WyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcyRequest();
        eskierowanie.KryteriaWyszukiwaniaSkierowanUslugobiorcyMT kryt=new XRis.eskierowanie.KryteriaWyszukiwaniaSkierowanUslugobiorcyMT();
        eskierowanie.IdentyfikatorUslugobiorcyOIDMT id_uslugobiorcy=new XRis.eskierowanie.IdentyfikatorUslugobiorcyOIDMT();
        id_uslugobiorcy.extension="111111111";
        id_uslugobiorcy.root="2.11.1111.1.111111.1.11111.1.1.111";
        kryt.idUslugobiorcy=id_uslugobiorcy;
        wsur.kryteriaWyszukiwaniaSkierowanUslugobiorcy=kryt;
        

        eskierowanie.WyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcyResponse response=os.wyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcy(kontekst,wsur);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(response.wynik.komunikat);
```

In SoapUI test suite it shows it should look like this:

```
    POST https://isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/services/ObslugaSkierowaniaWS HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
    SOAPAction: "urn:wyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcy"
    Content-Length: 5913
    Host: isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
    
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v20="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/kontekst/mt/v20180509" xmlns:v201="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/eskierowanie/ws/v20180509" xmlns:v202="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/eskierowanie/mt/v20180509" xmlns:v203="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/wspolne/mt/v20180509">
       <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-4774053CD62669762616081091569011" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><ds:X509Data><ds:X509IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=PL,O=CSIOZ,OU=P1 Integracyjne,CN=CC P1 SubCA WSS</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>45462786551181900</ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509IssuerSerial></ds:X509Data></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>CJRtZ7asgtnYVPYJPkmV93e6+ehpZDyv4RxnXg6lcHPrl5RBZhHPt3tdigdCHlOUO0lhh4daujiyulEnPkhHvjodNRDdjfHccKfHM6oojCDpB6mxVuZOKpuW2els8DwxGAu0XUM6pGL6HMndgSzeusK2DMZiBNRN4BfDSBYsWPU7TtpveywRvo090PNTpFuJV/E3g0JP5s2jHEFrHusDqjXPb4aJ/2Y2KEI8Q7b79Of0i5GApMxWF4ZBKmJ+rNHiNHH8nvcapLm0mNxkx6TIu0JXUVPmlKmcMR4YzXMb1M0VAPQ12o6sYEw3sDNUGv+NYpx2evF9fz4cIC/BfzhFnA==</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData><xenc:ReferenceList><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-4774053CD62669762616081091569192"/></xenc:ReferenceList></xenc:EncryptedKey></wsse:Security>
          <v20:kontekstWywolania>
             <v20:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidRoot">
                    <v20:wartosc>2.16.840.1.11111.3.4424.2.3.1</v20:wartosc>
                </v20:atrybut>
          </v20:kontekstWywolania>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-4774053CD62669762616081091569192" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-4774053CD62669762616081091569011"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any hints on how to go about this in C# would be much appreciated.

Btw is there a way to use tls certificate authentication when using svcutil as for now i'm just downloading all files via browser and then importing local files.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication179
{
    class Program
    {
        const string  URL = "//isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/services/ObslugaSkierowaniaWS HTTP/1.1";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                 "<soapenv:Envelope" +
                    " xmlns:oas=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"" +
                    " xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"" +
                    " xmlns:v20=\"http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/kontekst/mt/v20180509\"" +
                    " xmlns:v201=\"http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/eskierowanie/ws/v20180509\"" +
                    " xmlns:v202=\"http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/eskierowanie/mt/v20180509\"" +
                    " xmlns:v203=\"http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/wspolne/mt/v20180509\">"+
       
                      "<soapenv:Header>" +
                         "<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">" +
                             "<xenc:EncryptedKey Id=\"EK-4774053CD62669762616081091569011\" xmlns:xenc=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#\">" +
                                "<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p\"/>"+
                                "<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">" +
                                   "<wsse:SecurityTokenReference><ds:X509Data><ds:X509IssuerSerial>" +
                                   "<ds:X509IssuerName>C=PL,O=CSIOZ,OU=P1 Integracyjne,CN=CC P1 SubCA WSS</ds:X509IssuerName>" +
                                   "<ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509SerialNumber>" +
                                   "</ds:X509IssuerSerial>" +
                                   "</ds:X509Data></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>" +
                                "</ds:KeyInfo>"+
                                "<xenc:CipherData>" +
                                   "<xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>" +
                                "</xenc:CipherData>" +
                                "<xenc:ReferenceList>" +
                                   "<xenc:DataReference URI=\"#ED-4774053CD62669762616081091569192\"/>" +
                                "</xenc:ReferenceList>" +
                             "</xenc:EncryptedKey>" +
                         "</wsse:Security>" +
                         "<v20:kontekstWywolania>" +
                            "<v20:atrybut nazwa=\"urn:csioz:p1:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidRoot\">" +
                               "<v20:wartosc>2.16.840.1.11111.3.4424.2.3.1</v20:wartosc>" +
                            "</v20:atrybut>" +
                         "</v20:kontekstWywolania>" +
                      "</soapenv:Header>" +
                      "<soapenv:Body>" +
                         "<xenc:EncryptedData Id=\"ED-4774053CD62669762616081091569192\" Type=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content\" xmlns:xenc=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#\">" +
                            "<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc\"/>" +
                            "<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">" +
                                "<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsse11=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd\">" +
                                   "<wsse:Reference URI=\"#EK-4774053CD62669762616081091569011\"/>" +
                                "</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>" +
                            "</ds:KeyInfo>" +
                            "<xenc:CipherData>" +
                               "<xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>" +
                            "</xenc:CipherData>" +
                         "</xenc:EncryptedData>" +
                      "</soapenv:Body>" +
                 "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            string serialNumber = "45462786551181900</";
            string cipherValue = "CJRtZ7asgtnYVPYJPkmV93e6+ehpZDyv4RxnXg6lcHPrl5RBZhHPt3tdigdCHlOUO0lhh4daujiyulEnPkhHvjodNRDdjfHccKfHM6oojCDpB6mxVuZOKpuW2els8DwxGAu0XUM6pGL6HMndgSzeusK2DMZiBNRN4BfDSBYsWPU7TtpveywRvo090PNTpFuJV/E3g0JP5s2jHEFrHusDqjXPb4aJ/2Y2KEI8Q7b79Of0i5GApMxWF4ZBKmJ+rNHiNHH8nvcapLm0mNxkx6TIu0JXUVPmlKmcMR4YzXMb1M0VAPQ12o6sYEw3sDNUGv+NYpx2evF9fz4cIC/BfzhFnA==";
            
            XElement X509SerialNumber = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "X509SerialNumber").FirstOrDefault();
            X509SerialNumber.SetValue(serialNumber);

            XElement CipherValue = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "CipherValue").FirstOrDefault();
            CipherValue.SetValue(cipherValue);

            string xmlText = doc.ToString();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlText);

            WebRequest request = (WebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction" , "urn:wyszukanieSkierowanUslugobiorcy");
            request.Headers.Add("HOST", "isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl");
            request.Headers.Add("Connection" , "Keep-Alive");
            request.Headers.Add("UserAgent" , "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)");
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


        }
    }
}
```